# How to install Dart 3 on Mac os?

Tags: dart, homebrew

The documentation https://dart.dev/get-dart says:

```
 brew tap dart-lang/dart
 brew install dart
```

This installs Dart `2.18.6`

`brew upgrade dart`

This says:

`Warning: dart-lang/dart/dart 2.18.6 already installed`

The same documentation says:

```
About release channels and version strings
The Dart SDK has three release channels:

Stable channel: stable releases, updated roughly every three months; currently 3.0.6.

Stable releases are suitable for production use.
```

How to install this `3.0.6` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brew needs to know that latest stable version has changed.

It taps that info from the repo https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart that is why you need to do the first step when install.

Solution is to tell brew to tap again from the repo (like git fetching):

`brew update`

if prompted do the

`brew tap --repair`